# In Python 3.6 JSON module why do I have to use both loads and load?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am trying to persist some data to disk, I am attempting to use Python's JSON module but I can't access the data on simple `json.load` and I can't figure out why. Here's my code:

```
jsondata=json.dumps({'a':1,
     'b':'string',
     'c':{'k1':(1,3),'k2':(12,3)}})

f= open('jsonfile.json', 'w')
json.dump(jsondata,f)
f.close()

g=open('jsonfile.json', 'r')
result=json.load(g)
g.close()

print(result['b'])
```

This gives me the error *"TypeError: string indicies must be integers"*

However if I replace the access block with

```
g=open('jsonfile.json', 'r')
result=json.loads(json.load(g))
g.close()

print(result['b'])
```

It gives me the result I expect. I have read through the documentation a number of times and it seems like the simple `json.load` by itself should be sufficient. I can't figure out why I would have to use `json.loads` as well. I feel like I'm missing something. Any insight would be welcome.

Comment: Your `jsondata` holds string (serialised dict as a result of `json.dumps`), which you then put into a file. So, when you use `json.load(g)` you get back that string in result. Using `json.loads` on the result of `json.load` gives you your initial dict.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks петр костюкевич

Problem was I was converting it to a string before the dump so needed to convert it back. This code worked.

```
jsondata=({'a':1,
     'b':'string',
     'c':{'k1':(1,3),'k2':(12,3)}})

f= open('jsonfile.json', 'w')
json.dump(jsondata,f)
f.close()

g=open('jsonfile.json', 'r')
result=json.load(g)
g.close()

print(result['b'])
```